# How do I repair a Fat 32 Filesystem Partition "input/output error"

Tags: partitioning, error-handling, fat32

Some how the partition (Dev/sda2) partition got deleted.  So I use TestDisk to bring it back... The first time I did it it erase the whole hard drive... The second time it did restore the partition which is good.  But now it is giving me a error massage when I try to open it in Files(Gnome).

[image]

IF you need it in text here: Error when getting information for file '/media/ubuntu-gnome/Backup/User': Input/output error

Comment: check `dmesg` after getting this error for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Try running

```
sudo dosfsck -r
```

a few times and see if that fixes things.  Good luck.

Comment: This work for me, allows me delete the `Orphaned long file name part "2013-12-31--18-26-31 ALPS.KK1.MP1.V2.46`" thanks

Comment: Using -a option restores the FS automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem about an hour ago, and I was searching to find an answer, then i found this forum. I just fixed my usb, and here is what I did:

> sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sdXY

(Note: This FORMATS ALL DATA on your partition and fixes the problem.)

(Note: First unmount your device)

Now my usb is working as well.

Comment: THIS JUST FORMATTED MY DRIVE!!!

Comment: I'm so sorry for what happened to your drive. I had to tell that this format the partition but fixes the problem. I can recovery your hard just like it was before, but don't know how to send you a message. Give me your Gmail or telegram or Instagram ID, I'll help you recovery it as fast as possible. Sorry Again.

Comment: read above comment @JamieHutber

Comment: Lol I wish I could downvote you. When adding solutions like this, also say what it does, especially when it FORMATS YOUR DRIVE!!

Comment: @sansa I did so, didn't I?:)

Answer (score -1):

## Repair the file system

It seems your file system is corrupted.
You can attempt to fix it by executing this command in your Terminal:

> sudo fsck -y `/dev/sda2`

Replace `/dev/sda2` with the appropriate partition you want to fix.

Comment: `fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda2

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>`

Comment: What is the filesystem of /dev/sda2?