# Corrupted exfat usb flash drive

Tags: usb, fsck, exfat

I tried already the answers.
[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/999411/how-to-fix-input-output-error-on-usb-flash-drive)
[here2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147228/how-to-repair-a-corrupted-fat32-file-system)
[and here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/478124/how-do-i-repair-a-fat-32-filesystem-partition-input-output-error)

Output of fdisk -l:

[image: fdisk -l]

Output of fsck.exfat -p:

[image: fsck exfat -p]

Then the usb disconnects automatically. Mount or lsusb doesn't make it appear and i have to unplug and plug it again.

Output of dosfsck -r:

[image: Zero logical sector size]

I tried formatting the drive with the GUI Disks method. It just stopped working.

I also tried rm -rf to the data on the disk. The output was
Input/Output error on **empty** directories. Ls command afterwards same error.

fsck.exfat -v output:
[image: fsck.exfat]

I tried Windows as well but error is:
Unknown USB device (set address failed) and i tried the windows fixed. None worked.

So did i make this usb unusable? And yes i did remove safely the drive.

Comment: You can analyze the problem according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035) and if you are lucky, find a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Tried it. Seemed to be Confusion but i tried mkusb and after some time the device suddenly cannot get recognized from the system and have to replug it.

Comment: After some time ... sounds like an unusual problem. What happened after replugging (and retrying with mkusb)?

Comment: Please post output of terminal as code formatted text instead of as pictures: easier to read, possible to search and to copy. This could be a hardware failure.

Comment: @sudodus Same loop. It starts...and after some time...cannot get recognized.

Comment: @vanadium Yeah sorry about that. Most likely is a hardware failure i suppose. Fortunately the warranty still checks out. Will update on the answer if they can fix it.

Comment: @stavromachinima, I'm sorry, but must agree that 'everything' indicates that it is a hardware failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Flash drive was in warranty and the shop gave me a new one.